# Построение абстрактного синтаксического дерева исходного кода на Java

Tags: java, парсер

Мне необходимо построить ast программного кода и сохранить это в xml файл. Может кто-нибудь подскажет уже готовые библиотеки?

Answer (score 1):

У Eclipse есть достаточно интересный [инструмент](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) (+ [статья](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html)).

Честно, никогда не пробовал сохранять это в xml...

Answer (score 0):

Через Groovy можно - он понимает Java'овый синтаксис. На прошлом JPont'е Барух рассказывал: https://youtu.be/fu6z78YIKn0